# Simulink Stateflow: Wait for Parallel States

Tags: simulink, stateflow

I would like to create a state machine in Stateflow  that enters into multiple parallel states (A&B&C) and then exits to an end state (D) only when a condition from each parallel state has been achieved.  The picture demonstrated below exits when any of the exit conditions for any state in {A,B,C} is satisfied.  (In Enterprise Architect's state chart, I believe this would be a Synchronized state).

Is this possible to do in Stateflow? If so, how?

[image: Wait for Multiple States]

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you not just make 1 state? What is the added value of the parallel state with respect to just 1 state?

Comment: The three states are atomic states reused from a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work? [image]

You'll probably need to use atomic subchart mappings (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ug/mapping-variables-for-atomic-subcharts.html) to map variables in1, in2, in3 to some data in the corresponding atomic subcharts, and assign them in there.